# How to make tooltip appear beneath a <div> instead of covering it?

Tags: html, css

This code displays a tooltip containing five lines of information when a mouse hovers over this section: `<div class="event1Bubble tooltip">`

Currently the tooltip completely conceals that `<div>` section from view when it appears. I would like it to instead appear directly beneath that section, so my users can see the section and the tooltip at the same time.

Could someone show me how to modify my code to achieve this without altering any of the existing styling please?

```css
.Timeline {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 500px;
  margin-left: 80px;
}

.event1 {
  position: relative;
}

.event1Bubble {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: rgba(158, 158, 158, 0.1);
  width: 130px;
  height: 60px;
  top: -70px;
  left: -15px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px rgba(158, 158, 158, 0.64)
}

.event1Bubble:after,
.event1Bubble:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: transparent;
  border-bottom: 0;
}

.event1Bubble:before {
  bottom: -10px;
  left: 13px;
  border-top-color: rgba(222, 222, 222, 0.66);
  border-width: 12px;
}

.event1Bubble:after {
  bottom: -8px;
  left: 13px;
  border-top-color: #F6F6F6;
  border-width: 12px;
}

.eventTime {
  display: flex;
}

.DayDigit {
  font-size: 27px;
  font-family: "Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif;
  margin-left: 10px;
  color: #4C4A4A;
}

.Day {
  font-size: 11px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-top: 10px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #4C4A4A;
}

.MonthYear {
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 10px;
  color: #9E9E9E;
  font-size: 9px;
}

.active {
  font-family: "Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif;
  color: #228B22;
  font-size: 11px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  align-items: center;
  margin-left: 12px;
  margin-top: -2px;
}

.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 480px;
  background-color: black;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 5px 0;
  padding-left: 5px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="Timeline">
  <div class="event1">
    <div class="event1Bubble tooltip">
      <span class="tooltiptext">id: 12345</br>
                                    starts_on: 2019-03-07</br>
                                    start_reason: something</br>
                                    ends_on:</br>
                                    end_reason:</br>
                                    type: something
          </span>
      <div class="eventTime">
        <div class="DayDigit">10</div>
        <div class="Day">
          Wednesday
          <div class="MonthYear">September 2018</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="active">Active</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: try add : `top: -100%;` to te tooltip, so it stands at the bottom of the relative parent

Comment: It doesn't work. It still covers the `<div>`, only difference is now the tooltip's bottom edge aligns with the bottom edge of the `<div>`, instead of its top edge aligning with the top edge of the `<div>`.

Comment: ...  so you tried, did you realize removing the minus sign worked ? it was a hint, answers is suppose to be posted below ;)

Comment: I didn't realise it was a hint, and I didn't realise that removing the minus sign makes it work until I saw the answer below. It's been years since I've done any CSS. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a `top` value of the height of the hovered container (60px in your case) to your absolutely positioned tooltip element.

Also by the way, `</br>` is invalid markup. It should either be a standalone `<br>` or a self-closing `<br/>` in X(HT)ML.

```css
.Timeline {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 500px;
  margin-left: 80px;
}

.event1 {
  position: relative;
}

.event1Bubble {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: rgba(158, 158, 158, 0.1);
  width: 130px;
  height: 60px;
  top: -70px;
  left: -15px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px rgba(158, 158, 158, 0.64)
}

.event1Bubble:after,
.event1Bubble:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: transparent;
  border-bottom: 0;
}

.event1Bubble:before {
  bottom: -10px;
  left: 13px;
  border-top-color: rgba(222, 222, 222, 0.66);
  border-width: 12px;
}

.event1Bubble:after {
  bottom: -8px;
  left: 13px;
  border-top-color: #F6F6F6;
  border-width: 12px;
}

.eventTime {
  display: flex;
}

.DayDigit {
  font-size: 27px;
  font-family: "Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif;
  margin-left: 10px;
  color: #4C4A4A;
}

.Day {
  font-size: 11px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-top: 10px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #4C4A4A;
}

.MonthYear {
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 10px;
  color: #9E9E9E;
  font-size: 9px;
}

.active {
  font-family: "Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif;
  color: #228B22;
  font-size: 11px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  align-items: center;
  margin-left: 12px;
  margin-top: -2px;
}

.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 480px;
  background-color: black;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 5px 0;
  padding-left: 5px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 60px;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="Timeline">
  <div class="event1">
    <div class="event1Bubble tooltip">
      <span class="tooltiptext">id: 12345<br>
                                    starts_on: 2019-03-07<br>
                                    start_reason: something<br>
                                    ends_on:<br>
                                    end_reason:<br>
                                    type: something
          </span>
      <div class="eventTime">
        <div class="DayDigit">10</div>
        <div class="Day">
          Wednesday
          <div class="MonthYear">September 2018</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="active">Active</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```